# Change from "Import" to "Direct Query" in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, m

I have 2 Queries in **Power BI**

one is **Import** and the other is **Direct Query**

I was looking at the **Advance Editor** for both queries.

they both look exactly the same, no difference what do ever

How can I change **Import** query to become **Direct Query** from the **Advanced editor**?

**Import query script**

```
let
    Source = Sql.Database("DSServer", "DSDB", [Query="EXEC stat_DailyNumbers"])
in
    Source
```

**Direct Query script**

```
let
    Source = Sql.Database("DSServer", "DSDB", [Query="EXEC stat_DailyNumbers"])
in
    Source
```

Comment: You can switch from DirectQuery to Import mode **but** you can't switch from Import mode to DirectQuery! check the detail workaround at [Power BI: Switch from Import to DirectQuery Mode](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/switch-import-to-directquery-mode-powerbi/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***You cannot switch between query methods.***

Workaround:

```
 1. copy the code from your advanced editor to notepad.
    
 2. Create a new query, where you will be able to choose direct query / import. 
    
 3. Open advanced editor for the new query and paste the code you copied earlier.
```

Answer (score 2):

no posible. Recread query in ReportServer PowerBi not possible.